# Gre counting question

Tags: combinatorics

Two men and two women are to be selected from $5$ sets of twins, where each set consists of $1$ man and $1$ woman. If only $1$ person from each set of twins may be selected for the group, what's the total number of distinct group that can be formed?

It seems a lot if I count by hand, the answer is $20$, but I keep counting either excess or lower to it, anyone see the pattern could help me to count quickly and accurately?

Comment: Are you sure the answer is 20? I get the answer as 30.

Comment: Not sure actually, the answer could be wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

Select the 2 men from the 5 sets in $\binom 52=10$ ways.

Now, you can't select a woman from those 2 sets already selected, so you select 2 women from the remaining 3 sets in $\binom 32=3$ ways.

By the rule of product, you can form the committee in $10\times 3=30$ ways.

---

Another approach would be to first select 4 sets in $\binom 54=5$ ways. Now, select two of these 4 sets for the men in $\binom 42=6$ ways and the women are automatically determined from the remaining 2 sets, so by the rule of product, form the committee in $5\times 6=30$ ways.